# Column with multiple auto increments

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

is it possible to create an auto-increment in a table using as reference another column of the same table?

I have a customer table with the columns id, position and company_id. I need each companion to have an auto increment.

in short ... I need a column to have several auto increments for each company

example:

```
-------------------------------
| table client                |
-------------------------------
| id | position | company     |
-------------------------------
|  1 |    1     | company one |
|  2 |    2     | company one |
|  3 |    1     | company two |
|  4 |    3     | company one |
|  5 |    2     | company two |
|  6 |    4     | company one |
|  7 |    5     | company one |
|  8 |    3     | company two |
|  9 |    6     | company one |
-------------------------------
```

I need the column position as auto increment for each companion. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: As a general answer, no, SQL does not offer you a solution for this. You can do it by a synchronized trigger, though. What's the specific use case?

Comment: @TheImpaler, I don't think a "synchronized trigger" is supported by MySQL. In MySQL, one would have to use an explicit table lock to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather painful to do *as a column stored in the table*.  However, it is easy to calculate when you need it using `row_number()`:

```
select c.*,
       row_number() over (partition by company order by id) as position
from client c
order by c.id
```